# HTTP 302 chained calls, with cookies and login

Tags: python, http, session, cookies, https

I have tried googling before posting it here so i am not sure if i am using the right words to search or the answer isn't there (thats impossible)

Anyways, before i start, this is first time I am touching python, so please be gentle.

I am trying to learn python and the best way to do it is by working on my own project. The project i chose, is to automate some internal websites. These websites use cookies, authentication, sessions and chained calls (302).

I wrote this code

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
my_url = 'https://test.company.com/'
opener = urllib2.build_response (urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
resp = opener.open(my_url)

print resp.read()
```

Now its doing what it is suppose to do but since i am learning there are few things that i need to get conrol of

1. I don't want to do the chain redirects if its 302. I want to do it manually
2. I want to extract the sessions so that with every request which i will be doing (with 302 location header), I can add that session/cookie
3. any tutorial which helps me understand python and http will be appreciated. I am already taking course at codecademy.com

Comment: May I suggest that you work through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) in its entirety? It will answer many of your questions before you even ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with `[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library it is easier to use and as powerful as urllib

```
#by using false on allow_redirects parameter request wont get redirected
r = requests.get('http://website.com', allow_redirects=False)
```